# android tv leanback application list

Tags: android, android-intent, action, panel, leanback

As part of developing a *custom launcher* application for **Android TV**, I have to show an apps list side screen based on installed apps list in the device.

To open the notifications screen on the device there is a simple action: 
`"com.android.tv.action.OPEN_NOTIFICATIONS_PANEL"`

```
String notificationAction = "com.android.tv.action.OPEN_NOTIFICATIONS_PANEL";
Intent openNotificationPanel = new Intent();
openNotificationPanel.setAction(notificationAction);
startActivity(openNotificationPanel);
```

Unfortunately after searching on the network, I did not find the appropriate action to open a screen of the list of applications.

I understood that there should be an intent action that would give me the complete list of apps installed.

It would be very helpful if someone can share the right intent action for this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I figured that google has added an action intent from sdk version 28 (pie) -

```
    Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS
```

The implementation -

```
    Intent openAllAppsScreenIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS);
    startActivity(openAllAppsScreenIntent);
```

Comment: Hi, I have now similar problem. Can you share result of certification and if using that approach (Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS) meets the certification requirements?